# Need to check if UITableViewCell is in array returned by visibleCells method in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to figure out if a particular index of a UITableViewCell is contained in the array returned by the method "visibleCells".  I am able to use the method "indexPathsForVisibleRows", but I am trying to figure out how to use the "visibleCells" method.  At the moment, all I am able to do is get the array, and simply print out its contents like this:

```
NSArray *test = [_table visibleCells];

    for (NSString *i in test) {
        NSLog(@"index is: %@", i);
    }
```

which gives me the following output:

```
index is: <UITableViewCell: 0x715dae0; frame = (0 132; 247 44); text = 'Item 3'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x715d9d0>>
2013-06-13 13:34:19.296 SimpleTable[1203:c07] index is: <UITableViewCell: 0x715e170; frame = (0 176; 247 44); text = 'Item 4'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x715e060>>
```

I need someone to show me how to check if a particular index is contained within this Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] containsObject:[tableView indexPathForCell:cell]) {
    // the cell is visible
} else {
    // the cell is not visible
}
```

It should be noted that there is a crash risk doing the above...
Using `containsObject` will also work if you use `visibleCells`.

```
if ([[tableView visibleCells] containsObject:cell]) {
    // the cell is visible
} else {
    // the cell is not visible
}
```

As a side note on your code:

```
NSArray *test = [_table visibleCells];

for (NSString *i in test) {
    NSLog(@"index is: %@", i);
}
```

The for loop is wrong because `test` doesn't hold instances of `NSString`, it holds instances of `UITableViewCell`...

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply.  Can you show me an example of using visibleCells?  If I can't use indexPath, can you show me using some other object (like UITableViewCell)?